# how to add *ngIf Template strings in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add a template string in typescript, and I want to add * ngIf.

can you play it?  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't.

`*ngIf` is structural directive designed for template side only by Angular team.

You can add some condition/variable and depending on that condition you can toggle i.e `*ngIf` into the template